# Create Two Executables from Single Project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2012 that currently has two projects:

1. Main application
2. Settings application

They both reference the same data file and use the same data model files (in the main application project).

What I'd like to do is allow the user to either open the settings application interdependently or open a setting window from within the main application.  This way they can modify settings while the application is running, or not.  Also, any changes made while running are instantly reflected.

I tried simply adding the settings application project as a dependency to the main application, so I could open the window, but that would create a circular dependency; because my setting application relies on the main apps data model.

How can I tidy up my code to allow the user open a settings window from within the application or via an external executable?

Comment: If you want it in one project, you could use command line switches to indicate you want to show the settings, e.g. `myApp.exe --settings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably have three projects:

- Shared data model class library
- Main application UI
- Settings UI

That way the main UI can depend on the settings UI without causing a circular dependency.

Or of course you could put all three within the same single executable project, and simply not have the settings UI as a separate binary...

Comment: Thank you.  After all that, I just stuck it all into the same executable... I can always separate it later if the need for two executables comes up (which I can't see right now, honestly).